# Program is not allowing decimal output

Tags: java, user-interface

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int num = (Integer)this.jSpinner1.getValue();
        int d = (Integer)this.jSpinner2.getValue();
        int val = (num / d);
        jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(val));
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int num = (Integer)this.jSpinner1.getValue();

    int d = (Integer)this.jSpinner2.getValue();

    int val1 = (int) ((double)num / (double)d);
    jTextField2.setText(String.valueOf(val1));
    }
```

I am creating a program that uses a numerator and denominator the uses buttons to display integer and double value. The program works but it does not show decimals. It usually goes to the closest whole number. Basically what I need is help with getting decimals to show up in the output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb3dH.jpg

Comment: You are casting val1 to int, so you lose decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are explicitly declaring your output variable as `int`.

Return a `double` value, or for better precision, a `BigDecimal`.

**Example**

```
BigDecimal output = new BigDecimal(num)
    .divide(new BigDecimal(d), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```